# What does "Variable" means in python? Is it a standard function?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have some python code that I have to read and understand.

In one line I find

```
 img = Variable(torch.from_numpy(img.transpose(2, 0, 1)[np.newaxis,:,:,:]).cuda().float(), volatile=True)
```

what is this `Variable` I am seeing? When I use the IDE to find the definition it says 'No definition found for Variable' which makes me suspect it is a standard function in python. I Obviously can not google "Variable" for python because I will get countless definitions of what a variable is in python.

Has anyone seen a line like this before? Where Variable is being used as a function?
t

Comment: I have not seen that as a standard function. Perhaps if you add a bogus parameter (say `fishing_int_the_dark=False`) the traceback can tell you which line of code it calls to

Comment: That's not a built-in, presumably it's something from pytorch - that you have perhaps not actually imported yet, so your IDE can't find it.  I see `from torch.autograd import Variable` in some sample code online.

Comment: if you are in **pdb** or the like you could `print(Variable.__module__)` and it would tell you where it came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Variable` is not an inbuilt class. It is under module `torch.autograd`

> A Variable wraps a Tensor. It supports nearly all the API’s defined by a Tensor. Variable also provides a backward method to perform backpropagation. For example, to backpropagate a loss function to train model parameter x, we use a variable loss to store the value computed by a loss function. Then, we call loss.backward which computes the gradients  ∂loss/∂x for all trainable parameters. PyTorch will store the gradient results back in the corresponding variable x.

[Source](https://jhui.github.io/2018/02/09/PyTorch-Variables-functionals-and-Autograd/)